# Tooltip Dissappears when Mouse Cursor Is In Tooltip Content Area

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextedit, qtooltip

I am having simple Text Editor. Once I hover on word, the tooltip text which is defined in tooltips dictionary is visible. It works fine. But I have following problem. When tooltip text is too large, it appears at the same position as mouse cursor is located which makes tooltip visible just 1 second.

I have some few tooltips which sometimes cover whole screen. Is it possible to somehow avoid it.

Here is the minimum working code:

Python version: 3.11.0
PyQt5 version: 5.15.7

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolTip
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor


tooltips = {'Hello': ('Tooltip for Hello' * 20 + '\n') * 100 }


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_edit = MyTextEdit("Hello")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)
        self.resize(800, 600)

class MyTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)    

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        
        tc_temp = self.cursorForPosition(event.pos())
        tc_temp.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
        word = tc_temp.selectedText()
        
        if word in tooltips:
            self.show_tooltip(tooltips[word])
        else:
            QToolTip.hideText()

        self.setTextCursor(tc)
        
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


    def show_tooltip(self, tooltip_text):
        if tooltips:
            pos = self.cursorRect(self.textCursor()).bottomRight()
            pos = self.mapToGlobal(pos)
            QToolTip.showText(pos, tooltip_text)        


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Use [QWhatsThis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwhatsthis.html) instead. In your example, you can simply replace `QTooltip` with `QWhatsThis`. Click anywhere with the mouse or press a key to close it. If you want to get mouse-move events whilst it is open, install an event-filter on the application.

Comment: @lilson While I understand the issue in concept, having a tool tip that covers the *whole* screen **is** the problem. Even if QWhatsThis may partially solve the issue of the disappearing text, it doesn't really solve the *real* issue: there is **too much text** that requires too much space. And even assuming that there are valid reasons to show so much text, if showing it covers almost (if not more!) than the screen area then QToolTip (or QWhatsThis) is certainly not a valid solution. You should eventually consider an alternative approach: a "summary" tooltip that can be expanded in a »

Comment: @lilson » separate dialog or popup, or a smaller widget that considers the screen area, uses a **reasonable** portion of it, and shows the full text in a scroll area like a readonly QTextEdit. Having a text shown in such a huge area is quite annoying and distracting (not to mention, difficult to read) if it just pops up just by hovering words. Also, remember that `cursorForPosition()` always returns *valid* cursor positions even if the mouse is completely outside any text, including blank areas. You should probably consider the `hitText()` function of the document's `documentLayout()` instead.